# Cucumber 6.9 java8, cannot convert from DataTable to custom type

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I want to register my custom type in order to automatically get a list from datatable.

Despite there are many sources refering to **TypeRegistryConfigurer** class, this appears to be deprecated in latest cucumber core version.

I tried to look at [this source](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/datatable/java/datatable/src/test/java/io/cucumber/datatable/DataTableTypeRegistryTest.java) so I did this:

```java
public class BurpStepDefs implements En {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private static final DataTableType ENTRY =
            new DataTableType(CartInput.Article.class, (java.util.Map<String, String> entry) ->
                    objectMapper.convertValue(entry, CartInput.Article.class));

    private final DataTableTypeRegistry registry = new DataTableTypeRegistry(Locale.ENGLISH);

        public BurpStepDefs() {

        registry.defineDataTableType(ENTRY);

        Given("burped", () -> {

        });

        When("burping", (DataTable o) -> {
            o.asList(CartInput.Article.class); // goes wrong
        });

        Then("burp", (DataTable o) -> {

        });

    }
}
```

This is the feature file

```
Feature: operate with customer cart
  Verify all cart operations

  Scenario: scenario burp
    Given burped
    When burping
      | BIRP        | 1 |
      | BYRP        | 1 |
    Then I burp
      | BIRP        | 1 |
      | BYRP        | 1 |
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't convert DataTable to List<it.infocert.ecommerce.checkout.model.CartInput$Article>.
Please review these problems:

 - There was no table entry or table row transformer registered for it.infocert.ecommerce.checkout.model.CartInput$Article.
   Please consider registering a table entry or row transformer.

 - There was no default table entry transformer registered to transform it.infocert.ecommerce.checkout.model.CartInput$Article.
   Please consider registering a default table entry transformer.

Note: Usually solving one is enough
```

Any hint ?

**EDIT**

After reading @M.P. Korstanje and [cucumber specs](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/) (At fist I thought docs were deprecated) I solved with this:

```java
DataTableType((java.util.List<String> entry) -> {

    final var output = new CartInput.Article();
    output.setName(entry.get(0));
    output.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(entry.get(1)));
    output.setOperationId("A");
    return output;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using bits and bobs from Cucumbers internal API. However the entirety of Cucumbers lambda DSL is contained within the `En` interface (and it's parent interface `LambdaGlue`). So to define a single data table entry transformer you would do:

```java
public class BurpStepDefs implements En {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public BurpStepDefs()
        DataTableType(
                (Map<String, String> entry) -> objectMapper.convertValue(entry, CartInput.Article.class));
    }
}
```

If you are using a modern IDE you can also type `this.` inside the constructor and trigger auto-complete (ctrl+space) look the suggestions that are available.